# ASP.NET Web API Get Method- Can i do the same with Post method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

this is a Get method in my controller to make a new user.

```
[HttpGet]
public string MakeUser(int number, string name, string surname)
{
    const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    string pass = "";
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        pass += chars[r.Next(0, 62)];
    }

    string firstTwoo = name.Substring(0, 2);
    string firstThree = surname.Substring(0, 3);

    return "Your username is: " + firstTwoo + firstThree + "\nYour password is: " + pass;
}
```

And this is the RunAsync method in my Console.

```
public static async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        Console.Write("Your username: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Your surname: ");
        string surname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Please type a number between 5 and 10: ");
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4688/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // HTTP GET
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/test?number=" + number + "&name=" + name
            + "&surname=" + surname);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string password = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
            Console.WriteLine("\n*****************************\n\n" + password);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is; is it possible to do the same with post method? If it is then how? Thank you very much.

Comment: You could do this as a POST request and send the password in the response header back. Without looking at any security issues.

Comment: Thanx, but how can i pass 3 parameters in Post method. I have tried and i could not succeed.

Comment: You could make a `User` class and pass the whole class in the POST request (which I would recommend). Or you pass 2 parameters through the url and one in the body.

Comment: I will try this. And i have any other problem too. I didnt succed with Get method yesterday and this morning wel. I didnt understand it, because the only thing that i did was to shut the computer down. Does IIS cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync`:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
//for security purposes, I think you should be adding an authorization token to the header like this, but it doesn't look like you have any security in place
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization"," Bearer " + token);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, object);
```

In `MakeUser` set the parameter to the `object` containing `number`, `name`, and `surname` and check the `ModelState.IsValid`

**EDIT**

```
public class User
{
    public int number { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string surname { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

From Nick Bailey's comment below:

> ...in this case there's no reason to use more than one object in the POST. It's generally better OOP practice to minimize the number of parameters to functions by grouping them into logically coherent entities.

Comment: Thanx, but how can i pass 3 parameters in Post method. I have tried and i could not succeed. Security is not important, because that is for a homework and it is done, but i wanted to know if i coud use Post method too.

Comment: @AttilaAlan make a class out of the three paraneters. you can only post a single object.

Comment: I will try this. And i have any other problem too. I didnt succed with Get method yesterday and this morning wel. I didnt understand it, because the only thing that i did was to shut the computer down. Does IIS cause this?

Comment: @tebubbs That's not true, you can have a post method with multiple parameters by either providing some parameters from the URL, or by using a custom ModelBinder. However, in this case there's no reason to use more than one object in the POST. It's generally better OOP practice to minimize the number of parameters to functions by grouping them into logically coherent entities.

Comment: @NickBailey ooo I see. thank you. now I should've remembered the URL method, but I didn't know about custom ModelBinder.. still fairly new to WebAPI.